# Повторное выполнение Observable

Tags: rxjava, rxandroid

```
Observable<Collection> request1=...
Observable<Collection> request2=...
                        .doOnNext(collection->{
                              boolean isFull = collection.isFull();
                        };
Observable.concat(request1, request2);
```

Трудность в том, чтоб на основе флага `isFull` в `request2` необходимо повторить выполнение цепочки вызовов `request1` и `request2`. То есть, если `isFull = false`, то заново выполнить `request1`, а затем `request2`, итак 5 раз, если и на 5й раз `isFull = false`, то бросать `error`.

Comment: Ну так организуйте цикл с соответствующими условиями выхода. В чём конкретно проблема?

Answer (score 1):

Если я правильно понял как работает `repeatWhen`, то как то так:

```
Observable.concat(request1, request2)
        .repeatWhen(completed -> collection.isFull() ? Observable.error(error) : completed);
```